# Why does Lazarus give a 'SigSegV' error? (HydraDM, HydraDM64)

Tags: segmentation-fault, lazarus

I created an empty Lazarus project and tried to compile it to test the settings of the compiler on my Windows 7 PC. Even though this was a fresh installation without any specific settings, the debugger gave me a 'External Error: SigSegV', when I closed the binary in the Lazarus environment. After that I was thrown into the assembly screen.

This error only occured, when using Lazarus. Launching the application under Windows did not produce any errors or lingering applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research on the internet, I found out, that the processes 'HydraDM.exe' and 'HydraDM64.exe' were responsible for this error. After killing both processes, the program ran fine in Lazarus.